# How can I make ServiceStack v3 conform to jsonapi.org standards?

Tags: json, ember.js, servicestack

I am attempting to utilize an Ember.js front-end with a ServiceStack v3 backend.  The issue I'm running into is that Ember Data is expecting JSON as per the jsonapi.org standards like so:

```
[{"clients":
    [
       {"clientID":80,"name":"Test Client 6","acronym":"TCL6","website":"http://www.tcl6.com"},  
       {"clientID":81,"name":"Test Client 7","acronym":"TCL7","website":"http://www.tcl7.com"}
    ]
}]
```

But ServiceStack serializes the data into the following:

```
[{"ClientID":80,"Name":"Test Client 6","Acronym":"TCL6","Website":"http://www.tcl6.com"},
 {"ClientID":81,"Name":"Test Client 7","Acronym":"TCL7","Website":"http://www.tcl7.com"}]
```

Forcing me to implement custom logic on the front-end to "massage" the data into the appropriate format.  I would like to avoid performing this conversion on the client side and implement it directly into the back-end's responses.

Any assistance or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell ServiceStack's JSON Serializer to emit `camelCase` property names with:

```
JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
```

You will also want to use a type that matches the shape of the JSON you want to return, e.g:

```
public class JsonApiClients
{
    public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Demis!!  I'm guessing I would need to implement a custom serializer to wrap the returned JSON array in the approprate type?

Comment: @slashp I've updated the question, you'll also need to use a model that matches the shape you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a serializer, something like this:

```
App.ClientSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
      return {
        "client": payload
      };
    }
});
```

Comment: This was the direction I was planning to take at first, but I would rather implement the logic server-side.  Either way, thanks for the repsonse.

Comment: leveraging Ember's adapters and serializers can make your code work in 5 minutes and give you time to fix the backend :) moreover, it gives you a proof that the code will work with the API you defined :)

Comment: however it's always good to implement it on the server side if there's no other tool using your API