# Ember and Rails has_many relationship

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, ember-data

I have two models, Project and Image, which have a has_many relationship (projects have many images). I am using Rails as an API and Ember on the front end.

The issue I am having is that I can't get the image data to pass to ember.

I have the following setup:

**Rails End**

app/models/image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  mount_uploader :project_image, ImageUploader
end
```

app/models/project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true

end
```

app/serializers/image_serializer.rb

```
class ImageSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :project_image, :project_id
end
```

app/serializers/project_serializer.rb

```
class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :client, :tags, :description, :start_date, :end_date
  has_many :images
end
```

**The Ember end**

app/assets/javascripts/store.js

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: 'api/v1'
})

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({});
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({});
```

app/assets/javascripts/routes/projects.js

```
App.ProjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() { 
    return this.store.find('project') 
  }
})

App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(params) { 
    return this.store.find('project', params.project_id) 
  }
})
```

app/assets/javascripts/models/project.js

```
App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  client: DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  start_date: DS.attr('string'),
  end_date: DS.attr('string'),

  images: DS.hasMany('image',  {async: true})
});
```

app/assets/javascripts/models/image.js

```
App.Image = DS.Model.extend({
  project_image: DS.attr('string'),
  project_id: DS.attr(),

  project: DS.belongsTo('project')
});
```

The JSON output I am getting from this when I visit localhost:3000/api/v1/projects.json is

```
{
  "project":
    {
      "id":8,
      "client":"example client",
      "tags":"example tag",
      "description":"some description",
      "start_date":"April 13",
      "end_date":"June 13",
      "images":[
        {
          "project_image":
            {
              "project_image":{"url":"/uploads/image/project_image/6/logo.jpg"}
            },
              "project_id":8
         }
       ]
     }
   }
```

I am pretty sure the format is wrong here for ember as the image data is not making it into the chrome ember inspector (project data is working fine other than the no images).

If anyone has any ideas on where I am going wrong with this it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output JSON could be in this format:

```
{
  "project": {
    "id": 8,
    "client": "escapethecity",
    "tags": "Wireframing, UI Design",
    "description": "",
    "start_date": "April 13",
    "end_date": "June 13",
    "images": [1],
  },
  "project_image": {
    "id": 1,
    "url": "/uploads/image/project_image/6/Eagle_logo_v7_no_tail.jpg",
    "project_id": 8
  }
}
```

So, firstly you need to specify the `id` of the image. Then, you can restructure the code in that way that you've got the array of `id`s in the `project` property (`"images": [1]`) and the separate `project_image` property for all the project images referenced in `project`.

Additionally, if you're providing all the information in one request, there's no need to declare `async: true` in the relationship.

I hope it helps :)

Note that it's one of the options. You can also check `DS.ActiveModelSerializer`; [here's a nice explanation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelSerializer.html).

EDIT:

My try on the serializer (though it's just dry writing, can be mistyped!):

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizePayload: function(payload) {

    // transform the project image
    payload.project_image = payload.project.images.map(function(image) {
      return {
        id: 1, // fake one!
        url: image.project_image.project_image.url,
        project_id: image.project_id,
        project: image.project_id
      };
    });

    // create project images ids (from the fake ones now...)
    payload.project.images = payload.project_image.map(function(image) {
      return image.id;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, do you know how I can go about restructuring the code to get the layout you format you've suggested. Sorry but I am fairly new to Ember, any guidance would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: sure, if you don't want to rearrange the backend now, you can write your own serializer (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27967042/3311093)) for `project` and then, if you feel everything's working, you can change your backend code

Comment: but still, you have to add the `id` field to `project_image` anyway to get it working... and then, transforming `payload` in the serializer should work :)

Comment: Really sorry I can't seem to get the payload to work, I keep getting syntax errors. Is there any chance you could edit your answer with an example of it. I have placed it in serializers/project_serializer so far, is that correct? :)

Comment: I assume you're using Ember App Kit or ember-cli, so having the file in serializers/project.js will be a good place

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! As you mentioned I need to add the image id to be serialised. This seems have made all the difference and it's finally in Ember! :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked! :) Would you mind selecting it a correct answer then?